# webView.loadDataWithBaseURL() does not work with special characters like %

Tags: android, webview

Can any one please tell which other characters need to be converted before loading the data in webview.

view.loadDataWithBaseURL("data:",htmlString, "text/html",
                        "utf-8", htmlString);

Answer (score 4):

Try `("data://", htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8", null)`.

That should load, although the back button behavior might not be correct.

Comment: but the requirement is for both i.e. data and back functionality.

Comment: Thanks this worked. putting `data://` allowed me to use `height="50%`.